# Mongoid database schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

We're making an application using Ruby on Rails with Mongoid.

I've been reading up on the documentation of mongoDB and the Mongoid gemregarding how to design the database schema when utilizing a document-based database. I've been going over it in my head for a while now, and would really appreciate some input from people with more experience than me to know whether or not I'm completely lost :p

Anywho, here's an overview (I've tried to keep it as simple as possible to keep the question facutal) of the appliction we're making:

The application consists of the following entities:

```
Users, Subjects, Skills, Tasks, Hints and Tutorials.
```

They are organized in the following manner:

```
Subjects consists of a set of 1..n Skills.

Skills consists of a set of Tasks, (sub-)Skills or both (i.e. skills can be a tree
structure, where one main skill (say, Geometry) is the root and other skills are 
child nodes (for instance, the Pythagorean Rule might be a sub-skill)). However, 
all skills, regardless of whether they have sub-skills or not, should consist of 
0..n tasks.

Tasks have a set of 1..n Hints associated with them.

Hints are each associated with a particular task.

Tutorials are associated with 1..n Skills (this skill can be either a root
node or a leaf node in a skill tree). 

Users can complete 0..n Tasks in order to complete 0..n Skills.
```

Now, we imagine that there will mostly be **read** queries called to the database for the collection of skills/tasks completed by certain users, and **read** queries to display the various skill trees associated with a subject. The main **write** queries will probably be related to relationship between various users and tasks, in the following form

```
User A completes Task B
```

and so forth. Also, we imagine that the size of the number of entitites would be as follows: Users > Hints > Tasks > Skills > Tutorials > Subjects

Currently, this is the solution we have in mind:

```
Subject.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :skills

Skill.rb (uses Mongoid::Tree)
has_and_belongs_to_many :subjects
embeds_many :tasks

Task.rb
embedded_in :skill, :inverse_of => :tasks
embeds_many :hints

Hint.rb
embedded_in :task, :inverse_of => :hints
```

We haven't really started implementing the tutorials and the connection between user and skills/tasks yet, but we imagine that the relationship between user and skill/tasks necessarily has to be N:N (which I guess is rather inefficient).

Is using a document-based database for this kind of application a bad idea? And if not, how can we improve our schema to make it as efficient as possible?

Cheers, sorry for the wall of text :-)

Comment: What was the main drive to use a NoSQL design for this schema?

Comment: Mainly just a desire to learn NoSQL.

Comment: I don't believe that NoSQL is the right solution for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my honest opinion unless some part of your data is going to be completely unstructured I see no need to use a NoSQL solution for your problem.
I'm going out from a point of view that you do have databases knowledge so you are familiar with MySQL/PostgreSQL/etc.
I sincerely believe that PostgreSQL (or Mysql for the matter) will be easier for you to set up, to write your code, to maintain and perhaps eventually to scale up.
My take on NoSQL is use it when you have unstructured datasets and you need the flexibility of adding fields on the fly, there are pitfalls using MongoDB.
It's not a silver bullet.

Some of the pitfalls are for instance, `in()`s are slow, if you write something to mongo and then want to immediately read it, you have to expect you won't get it (sharding in mongo), map reduce is kind of a hassle (I haven't tried the aggregate framework with `Moped` but it does look promising, sometimes indexing can have issues with sharded collections).

Comment: I do have database knowledge, and I'm sure we wouldn't have many problems implementing the database using PostgreSQL etc., but the fact that Khan Academy (a very similar application just with a much, much larger scope we used for inspiration when envisioning the application) uses NoSQL is what really made us believe NoSQL would be the way to go.